# Why can't I debug asyncio.get_running_loop() on pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-asyncio

I'm trying to test a jupyter notebook-safe wrapper for a library I maintain.

As part of that, I'm trying to simulate the jupyter environment by creating a new event loop in the test.

```py
# test.py
...
    def test_with_existing_event_loop(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        jupyter_safe_run_coroutine(some_async_coroutine())
```

```py
def jupyter_safe_run_coroutine(async_coro):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        loop.create_task(async_coro)
    except RuntimeError:
        asyncio.run(async_coro)
```

The problem is that even while there's a new loop set in the test, when I debug (pycharm) and step through the `jupyter_safe_run_coroutine` code, `get_running_loop()` always throws a `RuntimeError`.

When I try to step into it, it just doesn't, and skips to the except clause instead.

Any idea why?